# How to slow down hair dynamics?

Tags: dynamic

I'm currently working on a sci-fi project which involves a couple of hairs/cables/things which I want floating in the air. I'm in the right direction with the look i want, but i cant seem to slow down the speed at which they move. I'm controlling it with a turbulence and a force, but even at very low values the move quick.

I also tried to slow down the speed in the render settings, but this just results in a choppy animation. Any advice on how to tackle this?

Comment: it looks like the Flow value of the Force Field slows down the simulation?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the *Flow* value of the *Force Field* kind of slows down the simulation:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortantly this also quite drasticly alters the look of the 'distortion/bends' of the hairs. An i still end up with some twitching hairs, moving way to fast...